# What is a x-wily-servlet in the httpheader?

Tags: asp.net, security, servlets, xss

Anyone know what is as x-wily-servlet that it is an httpheader whenever a asp.net request is submitted?

Because I want to remove it. The auditor of the system that i am working on said that it is a possible security hole since in this x-wily-servlet it will show the ipaddress.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those headers come from CA Wily metrics. You may have this product to measure Web metrics from CA.

However, it is not security hole per se. It is what's called an information disclosure vulnerability. It is not critical, but yes, it provides useful information about your internal IP address scheme and the name scheme you are using in your servers. Something that usually don't want to have widely available.

Answer (score 0):

The header information by default is encrypted.

The following are some questions and answers around the introscope.agent.decorator.security encrypted setting:

Q. What is the key size for AES? 

A. A key size is a hard-coded private 16 byte array (128 bits)

Q. Where is the key maintained ? what protections are in place ? Is it passphrase encrypted ? 

A. The key is available in memory. There is no passphrase for this encryption. Only the key is used.

Q. Where does the decryption occur? On agent server itself or in MOM where the CEM component is running?

A. The data is encrypted on the agent and decrypted on the TIM.

Q. What data is captured and transported? 

A. x-wily-servlet information sent from agent to TIM is encrypted.